# FactoryBoy "create" strategy doesn't seem to save django model

Tags: django, qualtrics, factory-boy

Probably a silly question, but I've been banging my head against a wall for a little while now. 
I decided to try factory-boy library to simplify my tests and defined a factory:

```
from . import models
import factory

class QualtricsSurveyCacheFactory(factory.Factory):
class Meta:
    model = models.QualtricsSurveyCache

survey_id = "SR_1234"
qualtrics_username = "bla@blah.bla#bla"
survey_name = "fake"
```

However, when I do `QualtricsSurveyCacheFactory.create()` it returns model with id = None

```
>>> survey = QualtricsSurveyCacheFactory()
>>> print survey.id
None
```

I can `.save()` model after creation, but just curious why it doesn't do it automatically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You weren't using the correct base class for Django models.  Inherit instead from:

```
class QualtricsSurveyCacheFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):    
    ...
```

Then, `QualtricsSurveyCacheFactory()` will return a saved instance with a primary key.  Use `QualtricsSurveyCacheFactory.build()` if you want an unsaved instance.